# Calculation of an infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^3}{2^k} = 26$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could you give me some advice on how to calculate the following sum?
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^3}{2^k} = 26\end{aligned}$$

Thank you!

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Check [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6fb9/5e5e74ad44f58da103138170a67afa412666.pdf) paper for example. Transform $k^3$ to a polynomial of falling factorials, after use summation by parts, and finally take limits.

Comment: You can have a look at some similar questions from the past, such as:
[Infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072038),
[Find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432384) or 
[Solving for $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{8^n}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/698598)
BTW I found them [using this search in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%20%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E3%7D%7B2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^3x^k\tag{$x=\frac12$}$$

$$
\int_0^x\frac1{t_1}\int_0^{t_1}\frac1{t_2}\int_0^{t_2}\frac{S(t_3)}{t_3}\ dt_3\ dt_2\ dt_1 =\int_0^x\frac1{t_1}\int_0^{t_1}\frac1{t_2}\int_0^{t_2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^3(t_3)^{k-1}\ dt_3\ dt_2\ dt_1$$
$$\begin{align}
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^x\frac1{t_1}\int_0^{t_1}\frac1{t_2}\int_0^{t_2}k^3(t_3)^{k-1}\ dt_3\ dt_2\ dt_1 \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^x\frac1{t_1}\int_0^{t_1}k^2(t_2)^{k-1}\ dt_2\ dt_1 \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^xk(t_1)^{k-1}\ dt_1 \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k \\
& =\frac x{1-x}\tag{geometric series}
\end{align}$$

---

$$\int_0^x\frac1{t_1}\int_0^{t_1}\frac1{t_2}\int_0^{t_2}\frac{S(t_3)}{t_3}\ dt_3\ dt_2\ dt_1=\frac x{1-x}$$

$$S(x)=x\left(\frac{d}{dx}x\left(\frac{d}{dx}x\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac x{1-x}\right)\right)\right)$$

Then consider $x=\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& S_{0} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{0}}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}} \Rightarrow \color{red}{S_{0} = 1} \\ \\
& S_{1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{1}}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1 - 1}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1}{2^{n}} - S_{0} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow S_{1} + S_{0} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1}{2^{n}} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n + 1}{2^{n + 1}} = 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n}} = 2 \left[ - \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n}} \right] = - 1 + 2 S_{1} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow \color{red}{S_{1} = 1 (S_{0} + 1) = 2} \\ \\
& S_{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2}}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2} + 2 n + 1 - 2 n - 1}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{2}}{2^{n}} - 2 S_{1} - S_{0} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow S_{2} + 2 S_{1} + S_{0} = S_{2} + 3 (S_{0} + 1) - 1 =  2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{2}}{2^{n + 1}} = - 1 + 2 S_{2} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow \color{red}{S_{2} = 3 (S_{0} + 1) = 6} \\ \\
& S_{3} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{3}}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{3} - 3 n^{2} - 3 n - 1}{2^{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{3}}{2^{n}} - 3 S_{2} - 3 S_{1} - S_{0} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow S_{3} + 3 S_{2} + 3 S_{1} + S_{0} = S_{3} + 13 (S_{0} + 1) - 1 =  2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{2}}{2^{n + 1}} = - 1 + 2 S_{3} \\
& \qquad \Rightarrow \color{red}{S_{3} = 13 (S_{0} + 1) = 26} \\ \\
& \text{... etc}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I will add what commented previously. We have that

$$\Delta x^{\underline{k}}=kx^{\underline {k-1}}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum a^{k}\delta k=\frac{a^k}{a-1}+C\tag{1}$$

where $x^{\underline k}$ is a falling factorial. And the formula for summation by parts

$$\sum f\Delta g=fg-\sum {\rm E}g\Delta f\tag{2}$$

where $\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)$ and ${\rm E}f(k)=f(k+1)$. And we can write any monomial as

$$x^n=\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{{n\atop k}\right\}x^{\underline k}$$

where $\left\{{n\atop 1}\right\}=\left\{{n\atop n}\right\}=1$ and $\left\{{n\atop 2}\right\}=2^{n-1}-1$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$. Then

$$k^3=k+3k^{\underline 2}+k^{\underline 3}$$

Now setting $f(k)=k^3$ and $\Delta g(k)=\left(\frac12\right)^k$ and using $(2)$ and $(1)$ we get

$$\sum\frac{k^3}{2^k}\delta k=-\frac{k^3}{2^{k-1}}+\sum \frac{1+6k+3k^{\underline 2}}{2^k}\delta k$$

Now applying summation by parts again with $f(k)=1+6k+3k^{\underline 2}$ and $\Delta g(k)=\frac1{2^k}$ we get

$$\sum\frac{k^3}{2^k}\delta k=-\frac{k^3}{2^{k-1}}+ \left(-\frac{1+6k+3k^{\underline 2}}{2^{k-1}}+\sum\frac{6+6k}{2^k}\delta k\right)$$

and repeating again summation by parts we get finally

$$\sum\frac{k^3}{2^k}\delta k=-\frac{k^3}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{1+6k+3k^{\underline 2}}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{6+6k}{2^{k-1}}-\frac6{2^{k-1}}+C$$

Then taking limits

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{k^3}{2^k}=\sum\nolimits_1^{\infty}\frac{k^3}{2^k}\delta k=-\frac1{2^{k-1}}(k^3+9k+13+3k^2)\Big|_1^{\infty}=26$$

---

Maybe a more faster calculation is using the recursive formula for summation by parts

$$\sum f \Delta g=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\ \Delta ^k f\ \frac{{\rm E}^k}{\Delta^k}g$$